Find anti-derivative: $\int \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2+6x-5} dx$
A friend told me the teacher assigned $\int \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2+6x-5} dx$ to them for calculus 2 class. I threw every calculus 2 integration technique at it, and none of the works. I am almost certain that it doesn't have an antiderivative with the popular functions. Even Symbolab and Wolfram alpha can't solve it. am I missing something or is this actually not possible to solve (with calculus 2 techniques or maybe something a little more advanced but not too advanced)?

The antiderivative is not an elementary function

@SineoftheTime Thanks, I guess I wasted those 3 hours.

Are you sure there is no typo in the denominator? If it's a $+5$ instead of $-5$, there is a possible path, but not a simple one that's expected to be solved in calculus 2 ( I don't know what it's exactly, but speculating it to be somewhat basic)

Actually, I take that back. Both $+5$ and $-5$ have the same approach. Split denominator into partial fractions of the type $\frac{k1}{x+a}+ \frac{k2}{x+b}$ and treat as two integrals. Substitute $x+a=y$. Your integrals will be in the form of $Ei$ (exponential integral) after that point, which are not elementary functions
